# Criar lista encadeada com realloc()

Tags: c, lista, alocação, lista-encadeada

Estou precisando implementar uma lista simplesmente encadeada que não possua uma indicação de próximo, ou seja, ela deve funcionar como um vetor, acessando posições próximas na memória. Estou utilizando o comando realloc() para tentar implementar, entretanto estou obtendo erro quando vou acessar algum dos itens da lista.

Struct que estou usando:

```
    typedef struct Lista lista;

    struct Lista {
    char nome[81];
    char telefone[15];
    char celular[15];
    char endereco[101];
    };
```

Função para inserir na lista:

```
void insererealloc(lista **l, int t)
{
    *l = (lista*) realloc(*l, (t)*sizeof(lista));

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    printf("Digite o nome");
    gets((*l)->nome);

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    printf("Digite o telefone");
    gets((*l)->telefone);

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    printf("Digite o celular");
    gets((*l)->celular);

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    printf("Digite o endereco");
    gets((*l)->endereco);

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
}
```

Tudo certo até ai! O problema ocorre quando eu vou tentar "printar" os elementos da lista, estou acessando eles como um ponteiro, por exemplo: lista[i]->nome, onde i é uma posição qualquer. Qual a forma correta de acessar esses membros?

OBS: Sei que o gets() não é nenhum pouco confiável, entretanto estou apenas fazendo testes e fiquei com um pouco de preguiça de usar fgets() ou algo melhor.

Comment: Só com isto não achei como ajudar.

Comment: Qual informação está faltando?

Comment: Qual é o erro que ocorre na hora de exibir? Poste a linha onde você declara um elemento do tipo `lista`.

Answer (score 0):

Bom primeiramente um toque para que seu código fique mais legível. Quando se está trabalhando com struct e alocando-as dinamicamente é sempre mais interessante colocar o `typedef` como sendo um ponteiro, por exemplo:

```
typedef struct Lista *lista;
```

Assim, quando você se referir ao ponteiro criado com o tipo `lista`, ele já irá se tornar um ponteiro sem precisar dos milhões de *.

A função mais apropriada para você fazer esse tipo de escrita em uma struct sem dúvida são [getline](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html) e [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Porém tome cuidado, o fgets pode gerar buffer overflows que são devidos ao caractere '\n' que supostamente é colocado no vetor de caracteres, indico colocar sempre +1 espaço nos vetores.

O principal problema com o `gets` é que você não tem controle de quantos bytes serão usados nem colocados pelo usuário. Podendo assim causar sérios problemas de overflow.

Use as dicas que dei e provavelmente suas dores de cabeça com leituras de vetores de caracteres e structs ficarão mais leves.

=)

Answer (score 0):

quando você pega a posição de um ponteiro ele deixa de ser um ponteiro. ex:

```
lista *l;
for(in=0;i<n;i++)
    puts(l[i]->nome); // isso vai dar erro

    puts(l[i].nome); // isso não vai dar erro
```

ou

```
lista **l;
for(in=0;i<n;i++)
    puts(l[i]->nome); // isso não vai dar erro

    puts(l[i].nome); // isso vai dar erro
```

isso depende se for um ponteiro duplo ou simples, se for simples, use `[i].` e não `[i]->`